# Share variable between classes - Pane Constructors

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in Java and I would like to ask you a quite simple question which concerns classes:

I have a class that needs the name of a Pane that will be further introduced afterwards:

```
private final class CustomDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private final StyledDocument styledDocument = pane.getStyledDocument();   
    // etc etc
}


private void cree_ihm() {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    ((AbstractDocument) pane.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter());
    // etc etc
}
```

which for sure doesn't work because pane is defined afterwards. I think the problem is that I don't really understand how to deal with classes in a functions' environment.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. What do you need to do? It sounds like you need to use parameters. Otherwise, you can't use a variable at a point before it is defined

Comment: Sure but, I tried to include CustomDocumentFilter within the function cree_ihm() but that's illegal

Comment: What do you mean illegal? It is a private class so if you defined it in a different file, then you can't create your custom filter anyways

Comment: What type of variable is `pane` at `pane.getStyledDocument()`? You have `Container pane = getContentPane();`, which is what my answer assumes is that you want to use that same `pane` variable, correct?

Comment: It's a Container, as far as I know it's related to the graphic interface (I mean, getContentPane(); ). My goal is to call CustomDocumentFilter and apply it to the content of getContentPane(), that will filter some words within

Comment: Well, like I said `getStyledDocument()` is not a method for the `Container` class, which is returned by `getContentPane()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't use a variable in a field like that, so you'll need to use a constructor to do the field assignment.
2. The `java.awt.Container` class that is returned by `getContentPane()` does not have a `getStyledDocument()` or `getDocument()` method. You need a `JTextPane`.

Also not sure why you had a private class.

```
public final class CustomDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter 
{
    private StyledDocument styledDocument;
    private JTextPane pane;

    public CustomDocumentFilter(JTextPane pane) {
        this.pane = pane; // Not really necessary
        this.styledDocument = pane.getStyledDocument();
    } 

    // Override some DocumentFilter methods here like insert and remove
}
```

---

I assume this method is in another class somewhere?

```
private void cree_ihm() {
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(); // <-- Get a JTextPane from somewhere
    ((AbstractDocument) pane.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter(pane));

}
```

Comment: It returns this error: cannot find symbol
   styledDocument = c.getStyledDocument();
                     ^
  symbol:   method getStyledDocument()
  location: variable c of type Container

Comment: I don't think there is a typo... I don't know what this Container class that you are using is, but I just rearranged your code to use field variables properly. If getStyledDocument is not a method for this Container class, you'll get that error

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it: getStyledDocument() is part of a standard library. I better changed the title of my inquiry to "Pane constructor". Why do you need pane = c; ?

Comment: "Pane" is what you named your variable name, so "Pane constructor" doesn't mean much. Can you tell me what library you are using for the `Container` class? Because otherwise I will assume you are using [`java.awt.Container`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) which does not have a getStyledDocument method. And `pane = c;` isn't needed unless you plan to use that `pane` variable elsewhere in your `CustomDocumentFilter` class

Comment: @Carlos - Please see my edits, you need a `JTextPane`. I found the methods you are trying to call

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!!